# Powershell: manage excel data to create bar chart

Tags: powershell

I have a excel file which contains details or machines. Basically this file generated by SCCM team and they provide some details like heartbeat, hw inventory, model etc.

i am creating a powershell script to get the model type of machines and show them in bar chart. I am able to read the excel file by powershell but i don't know how can show them like this.

**e.g**

```
Dell - 5
HP - 10
IBM - 30
```

Here is the script which i have created.

```
#Declare the file path and sheet name
$file = "D:\HealthCheck_test.xlsx"
$sheetName = "DC01"
#Create an instance of Excel.Application and Open Excel file
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)
$objExcel.Visible=$false
#$red = 1;
#$orange = 1;
#Count max row
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
#Declare the starting positions
$rowHB,$colHB = 5,14 #pie
$rowModel,$colModel = 5,32 #bar
$rowHWInv,$colHWInv = 5,16 #Pie
$rowSite,$colSite = 5,40 #Bar
$rowOS,$colOS = 5,41 #Bar
#loop to get values and store it
for ($i=1; $i -le $rowMax-1; $i++)
{
$HB = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowHB+$i,$colHB).text
$Model = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowModel+$i,$colModel).text
$HWInv = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowHWInv+$i,$colHWInv).text
$Site = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowSite+$i,$colSite).text
$OS = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowOS+$i,$colOS).text
#$i
Write-Host ("I am reading data on row: "+$i)
[int] $hb = $HB


$Model = $Model
[int] $HWInv = $HWInv
 $Site = $Site
 $OS = $OS

        if($hb -ge 31){
            $red = $red + 1
        }
        if($hb -ge 14 -and $hb -le 30){
            $orange = $orange + 1
        }

}
$objExcel.quit()

Write-Host ("Total devices more than 30 days old: "+$red)
Write-Host ("Total devices 14-30 days old: "+$orange)
```

At the moment i can created the script for heartbeat like devices more than 30 days old and devices 14-30 days old.

I will show them in pie chart but i don't know how can i arrange data for model to create bar chart.

Can anyone advise me on this?

Comment: I did lots of googling and finally i thought i need to use two dimensional array. I am working on it now. Will let you know once its done.